# How to find XPath on Odoo?

Tags: xpath, odoo

I need to find correct XPath to product id on Odoo 9. I have tried this but it is complaining that "string" has some problem.

Error details:

```
View inheritance may not use attribute 'string' as a selector.
```

Code:

```
 <xpath expr="//page[@string='Order Lines']/field[@name='order_line']/form[@string='Sales Order Lines']/group/group/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
     <field name="image_small" widget="image"/>
 </xpath>
```

Comment: As the error is telling you: don't use attribute `string` as a selector. It is forbidden since Odoo V9 IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In odoo v9, you does not permitted to use string as selector in xpath.
So it is good practice to use name as selector in xpath.

You should try following :

```
<xpath expr="//page/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
    <field name="image_small" widget="image"/>
</xpath>
```

Or you can also write xpath like that,

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//form//field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
    <field name="image_small" widget="image"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I will try that.My question is how to find out the correct xpath? are you using any tool? because I want to find correct xpath for this as well.
<xpath expr="//page[@string='Order Lines']/field[@name='order_line']/tree[@string='Sales Order Lines']/field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
                    <field name="image_small" widget="image"/>
                </xpath>.I tried this but here is the error - Element '<xpath expr="//page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/group/group/field[@name='product_id']">' cannot be located in parent view

Comment: Error details:
Element '<xpath expr="//page/field[@name='order_line']/form/group/group/field[@name='product_id']">' cannot be located in parent view

Comment: @user6716466 it is best not to make such a big xpath expressions, they tend to break much faster. The shorter the xpath the better. Try <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="before">

Comment: @Yenthe it doesn't work and says "Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']">' cannot be located in parent view"

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a need for such a detailed selector? It seems that selector as simple as this would do the job perfectly well:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="before">
    <field name="image_small" widget="image"/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: The change seems to be on `sale.order` form view. He is trying to change the order_line form view, so your solution is correct. But it wouldn't be enough for the order_line tree view. ;-)